# Can an image be compressed before modifying

Tags: image-processing, histogram, video-processing, image-segmentation, image-compression

In general, do medical equipment users compress the image before modifying it? (*where:* "modify" means using histogram equalization, smoothing, image segmentation, etc)?

I am a newbie to image processing and eager to know about the basic working process of image processing.

Comment: Who are "they" ? What kind of application ? In general, operations in the compressed domain are difficult if not impossible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust To be precise ultrasound machine manufactures but I'm asking in general

Comment: No, I am asking what kind of image processing specifically. And why would they compress ?